# Shutil can't move files with special characters

Tags: python, shutil

```
can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
```

so every time there's a special character in my file's name, i can't move the file. Shutil.Copy is not an option since I have too many files.

Is there another library or another solution to this?

```
def run():
    #resize
all_files = [f for f in listdir("E:\\Images\\path\\") if isfile(join("E:\\Images\\path\\", f))]
for file in all_files:
    try:
        im = cv2.imread("E:\\Images\\path\\" + file)
        width = im.shape[0]
        height = im.shape[1]

        ratio = width - height

        print(width, height)

        if abs(ratio) < 1000:
            shutil.move(f"E:\\Images\\path\\{file}", f"E:\\Images\\path\\Square\\{file}")
            
        elif width < height:
            shutil.move(f"E:\\Images\\path\\{file}", f"E:\\Images\\path\\Horizontal\\{file}")

        elif width > height:
            shutil.move(f"E:\\Images\\path\\{file}", f"E:\\Images\\path\\Vertical\\{file}")
    except:
        print('error')
```

run()

Comment: Can you give an example of a filename/path that cannot be moved in this way? A sample of your code would help too. Also, what OS are you working with?

Comment: We need a [mre] -- enough details to see the problem ourselves and test proposed solutions.

Comment: @LindenNolet, ...okay, so this is on _Windows_. That makes this a lot harder to test -- all the free online sandboxes like http://repl.it/ are UNIXy.

Comment: @LancelotduLac Windows and python, i also updated the code.

Comment: An exception with stack trace would still be helpful, as would an example of a specific filename that fails (though maybe not helpful _to me_ unless this can happen on non-Windows platforms).

Comment: *print('error')* tells you that something has gone wrong but not *what* has gone wrong. How about a small change: *except Exception as e: print(e)*. Crude but effective

Comment: Incidentally, in this snippet (most of which is irrelevant for the q....) you use 3 different means of joining paths: `join` (presumably `os.path.join`), str concatenation, and f-strings.  Use one and stick to it (best would be `os.path.join`, and even better IMHO would be `pathlib.Path` and related operations).  This is unlikely to be the issue without seeing a failing path, although it just about could cause it, but is certainly doesn't help---and won't help you later when you come to maintain this!

Comment: Not relevant to the specific question but I suspect that the files you want to process are all of the same type (JPG?). If that's the case, the pathname processing that you currently have can be greatly simplified if you utilise *glob* with an appropriate filename extension pattern

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that I have no way of testing this so *caveat emptor*

This approach greatly simplifies the pathname handling and will also emit a meaningful error message if anything goes wrong.

There is, however, an assumption that you're only interested in JPG files. If that's not right then you'll need to make some minor adjustments.

```
import glob
import os
import cv2
import shutil

BASE = 'E:\\Image\\path'

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(BASE, '*.jpg')):
    try:
        im = cv2.imread(file)
        width = im.shape[0]
        height = im.shape[1]
        ratio = abs(width-height)
        if ratio < 1_000:
            target = 'Square'
        else:
            target = 'Horizontal' if width < height else 'Vertical'
        shutil.move(file, os.path.join(BASE, target, os.path.basename(file)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Failed to process {file} due to {e}')
```